# Which one to use Factory or Direct Model class in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, dependency-injection

I need to create product programmatically So either i can inject

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
```

or i can use

```
\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
```

from the factory i can create product model

Which one should i use.Tell me advantage and disadvantage of both

Answer (score 3):

## When to inject a Factory class

You should always inject a Factory class for any *newable* object. Newable objects are objects which cannot be directly instantiated, and generally require input to create, e.g. an ID, or some user data. For example, any model which will have data added, or requires data to be loaded/created is a newable object.

Non-newable (injectable) objects are classes which require no data to instantiate, and will not change over time.

Generally: if you can have more than one object of the class it's newable, if there should only ever be one object, it's injectable.

**Examples of newables:**

- Data models (product, customer, etc.)
- Collections
- Page results

**Examples of injectables:**

- Contexts
- Repositories
- Registry

You can read more about [dependency injection in the DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/depend-inj.html).

## Using the Repository pattern

I would like to suggest that you use  `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` to create products programatically, as this class is marked with the `@api` tag.

As per  [item 8.5 of  the Technical Guidelines](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/coding-standards/technical-guidelines/technical-guidelines.html#modularity) given by Magento:

> Only the `@api` code of any module can be referenced by other modules.

We should strive to only use `@api` code in our custom code.

To use the `save` method in the Product repository class, you need to pass in a `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface` object. To get this object, you can inject `\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory` and call the `create` method.

Below is a starting point for creating a product using the repository.

```
private $productRepository;
private $productInterfaceFactory;

public function __construct (
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productInterfaceFactory
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    $this->productInterfaceFactory = $productInterfaceFactory;
}

public function createProduct ()
{
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $newProduct */
    $newProduct = $this->productInterfaceFactory->create();
    $newProduct
        ->setSku('ABC')
        // ... other data
        ->setName('Abc');
    $this->productRepository->save($newProduct);
}
```

Comment: when should i use Factory class?

Comment: @KrishnanDaiva I've updated my answer to include information about factories